# Syntax error or access violation: 1064 on isset

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I keep getting

> 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''5'' at line 5'

with the '5' being whatever number is selected from the dropdown box.

here's the code i have so far pertaining to the issue.

```
if (isset($_GET['orderBy']) && $_GET['orderBy'] == 'rank' || $_GET['orderBy'] == 'release_year' || $_GET['orderBy'] == 'author'
                        || $_GET['orderBy']== 'publisher')

if (isset($_GET['returnLimit']) && $_GET['returnLimit'] == 1 || $_GET['returnLimit'] == 5 || $_GET['returnLimit'] == 10
                                || $_GET['returnLimit'] == 25 || $_GET['returnLimit'] == 50 || $_GET['returnLimit'] == 75
                                || $_GET['returnLimit'] == 100)
{
      try{

           $db = new PDO ("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=user", "user", "12345");
           $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
           $minimum = $_GET['minimumYear'];
           $maximum = $_GET['maximumYear'];
           $order = $_GET['orderBy'];
           $limit = $_GET['returnLimit'];

           $q = "SELECT * 
           FROM book 
           WHERE '$minimum' <= '$maximum' 
           ORDER BY '$order'
           LIMIT '$limit'";

           $query = $db->query($q);
           $statement = $db->prepare($query);
           $statement->execute();
```

From the error I'm getting, i'm guessing it's showing up because there's no number being passed to $limit, so the SQL query has nothing to **'LIMIT'**. I've checked the syntax, but can't figure out what i'm doing wrong, Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you somehow find the SQL statement alone, after that php stuff?

Comment: Echo the sql statement ($q) then try it in phpmyadmin to debug

Comment: try this $q = "SELECT * 
    FROM book 
    WHERE ".$minimum." <= ".$maximum."
    ORDER BY ".$order."
    LIMIT ".$limit;

Comment: I echoed my $q, and got 'SELECT * FROM book WHERE '1900' <= '2015' ORDER BY 'rank' LIMIT '5'', so it is passing the number it seems, but after that it shows the same error message.

Comment: @aimme I get **Warning: PDO::prepare() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in /home/user/public_html/PDO_Test/bookFetch.php on line 35

Fatal error: Call to a member function execute() on a non-object in /home/user/public_html/PDO_Test/bookFetch.php on line 36** when i use that.

Comment: @aimme I got it to work by deleting _$query = $db->query($q);_ and putting **$q** into my 'prepare' statement. I wonder why yours worked, but mine didnt. Thanks!

Comment: actually prepare stmt accept the string which would be basically query.
you can try one thing
1) remove the query line and put the query inside prepare stmt like this

$q = "SELECT * 
           FROM book 
           WHERE '$minimum' <= '$maximum' 
           ORDER BY '$order'
           LIMIT '$limit'";

           $statement = $db->prepare($q);
           $statement->execute();

Comment: basically query stmt would be used in certain situation when you don't have any parameter otherwise use the prepare stmt to get escaped from sql injection

Comment: @bornprogrammer thanks, that cleared things up for me.

Comment: glad to know this :)

Comment: I think you may want something like `WHERE book.year >= '$minimum' AND book.year <= '$maximum'`  The `WHERE` statement you have doesn't do anything useful.

Answer (score 1):

There are at least four major problems with your code, may be more.

- First, you are using quotes in the LIMIT clause. As well as in ORDER BY
- Second, you are not using prepared statements.
- Third, this query makes no sense at all.
- fourth, wrong prepared statement syntax.

change your code to

```
if (
       isset($_GET['orderBy']) 
    && in_array($_GET['orderBy'], array('rank','release_year','author','publisher'))
    && isset($_GET['returnLimit'] 
    && in_array($_GET['returnLimit'], array(1,5,10,25,50,75,100))
    )
{
           $db = new PDO ("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=user", "user", "12345");
           $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
           $min = $_GET['minimumYear'];
           $max = $_GET['maximumYear'];
           $order = $_GET['orderBy'];
           $limit = $_GET['returnLimit'];

           $q = "SELECT * FROM book WHERE release_year BETWEEN ? AND ? 
           ORDER BY $order LIMIT $limit";

           $statement = $db->prepare($q);
           $statement->execute(array($min, $max));
           $data = $statement->fetchAll();
```

Comment: Any reason not to parameterize the `$order` and `$limit`?